# Multiple activities in 1 Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

This question may seem dumb but I there is this thing that has been bothering.
I am kinda new in android development and I am trying to make android app with ringtone feature.
My app will contain roughly 20 sounds. My idea to create app: Press Long Click>Show new layout with buttons. I was thinking to create 20 XML layouts, 1 for each Song file in my app, and 20 activities, 1 for each layout.
Now Is there something like subclass or some replacement for Activity. 
Some other way to avoid using 1 activity per layout.
Something that can have on create set layout and everything like Activity and to be started via intent. To put those 20 ringtone activities all in 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int whatYouArePassingIn, long id) {
                Intent a = new Intent(NameOfCurrentClass.this, ClassWhichWillDisplay.class);
                a.putExtra("Key", whatYouArePassingIn);
                startActivity(a);
            }
```

Explanation:

`OnItemClick()` will allow send an intent from the current class to the class which will display and allow you to pass in a variable which you can give a name for. From the activity that opens up, you will be able to access this variable, in your circumstance, you will be passing in the sound instead of the whatYouArePassingIn variable.

This is what you can use you can use to access the variable:

```
mvariable = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Key");
```

Comment: Not exactly I am looking for a way to avoid creating 20+ activities instead I need some way to put all that in 1 activity

Comment: You could have an activity which sets the images/buttons depending on the variable that is passed in, for example, if mvariable is equal to "movie" then set all the buttons/text to be movie specific

Answer (score 0):

If you have 20 activities that only differ by what sound they're going to play, you should just make 1 activity and pass the sound as a parameter in the intent used to create the activity via `Intext.putExtra(name, value)`.

Comment: No no they are for Ringtones, 3 buttons in every Activity 1 for ringtone, alarm and notifications.